# How to seperate overlapping bars in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have a very unfortunate looking bar graph:

[image]

I'm generating this using the following R code:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- read.table("output.tab", sep="\t")
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=reorder(V1, -V2), y=V2, fill=V1)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", width=10) +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1), legend.position="none")
```

I don't know how to separate the bars. I've tried changing ggplot's aes width, I tried setting position="dodge", and a bunch of other things. Most of these still give me the following error:

```
position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

If anyone could help find a way to separate them it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how many bars are there? i.e. how many unique x values?

Comment: I currently have 270

Comment: Have you changed the width=10 in the geom_bar call? That't the most likely culprit.

Comment: Well I mean they do overlap less with a smaller width, but I want the bars to be wider than the default width of 1.

Comment: Keep in mind that just to fit 270 bars (and nothing else) on a standard screen resolution of 1920 pixels each bar can't be any wider than 7 pixels. That's very small. That might not be practical.

Comment: That's fair. I just need a wide enough width to fit in the x-labels, really.

Comment: Well, keep making the width smaller (and the graphics device larger) until they fit as best you can. I'm not sure text will be readable at that size, though.

Comment: How do I make the graphics device larger? I tried that too to no avail.

Comment: Why? What are you trying to convey? I suggest cut any x (gene?) `y<1`.

Comment: It would take too long to explain what I am trying to convey, I just want to know how to stop the overlapping; if its not possible I'll find another way

Comment: in your call to element_text, try adding on size=1, and seeing how low you can go for readability. The easiest way to resize a ggplot if you are in RStudio is to click zoom and resize the plot - the text should stay the same size. You can save it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a wall-sized area to print it on, try:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(V1 = paste0(1:270,sample(letters, 270, replace=TRUE)),V2 =runif(270)*10)
dim(dat)

png("thatswhatshesaid.png",width=5000,height=250, units = "px")
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=reorder(V1, -V2), y=V2, fill=V1)) +
        geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", width=1) +
        theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1), legend.position="none")
dev.off()
```

Obviously can't fit it here, but it doesn't overlap:
[image: sobig]
http://tinypic.com/r/1sl3py/8

But I question the usefulness of such a graph. Perhaps you can break the graph into components by some subcategory. Cramming 270 elements into a chart is seldom useful.